# Open Source Simulation program to work along with Python?

Tags: python, modelica

Do Modelica environments offer interfaces to the Python language so that

1. Building the system to be simulated in the visual modeling environment while the settings for the simulation are created wit Python. In this way, I will be able to run the simulation several times within an optimization algorithm in Python.
2. Building complex systems as functions in a language that I already know, for example, I want to create a function in Python that represent the system, then run this function from a "block".

Comment: I think you can find some of the required building blocks here: https://modelica.org/tools and here: https://fmi-standard.org/tools/ or maybe here: https://github.com/traversaro/awesome-fmi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually most Modelica simulation environments would offer interfaces to scripting languages like Python. Another alternative is to export a Modelica model using any simulation environment to so called Functional Mockup Units (FMU) which are stand-alone software programs. There are software solutions in Python for simulating an exported FMU multiple times, e.g. each with different values of parameters.
2. The Modelica language supports calls to external functions written in C/Fortran but not Python.

Comment: Did not know that the question (and hence the answer) violates the community guidelines. I have changed the answer accordingly. Can you provide a link to these specific guidelines?.